# Error during deploy of WAR in JBOSS 5.1

Tags: servlets, deployment, jboss, war

I don't understand why I get an error during deploying of my webapp. At first time the deploy works but from the second I get this error:

> DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
>     Deployment "vfszip:/C:/jboss/deploy/TestServlet.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.
>   jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: Web mapping already exists for deployment URL file:/C:/jboss/tmp/a6q5r3z-z5l3qt-hfcant4w-1-hfclha33-ta/TestServlet.war/

I read in several threads on the web that I have to add into WEB-INF folder the jboss-web.xml file. So i added with the following content, but I still get the same error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
   "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
   "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
  <context-root>/TestServlet</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

The AS is JBOSS 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<context-root>/TestServlet</context-root>` to `<context-root>TestServlet</context-root>`. '/' is not required here. Please try that. And one more thing, do you have ROOT.war in Jboss

Comment: Thank you, I Removed ROOT.war and renamed <context-root> content and it worked!
But one more question, why if I try to re-deploy the same war I get the same error? And what can I do?

Comment: I would suggest you to remove ROOT.war only and revert back jboss-web.xml, the problem here is JBoss 5 throw an exception when other application try to bind context to '/'. Therefore, after removing ROOT.war (and you try to install only one application) there is no other applications mapped to '/'. Then you will able to access  http://localhost:8080/TestServlet/whatever.jsp